# Unable to make php works on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, apache2

I have already apache working and i have created a virtual host but php is not working, im getting just plain text, this is the error during the install:

```
 Error found on processing:
 javascript-common
 libapache2-mod-php7.2
 libapache2-mod-php
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is what im doing:

```
sudo rm -Rf var/lib/dpkg/lock ; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

Also tried

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-mcrypt
```

Comment: In the first formatted text block please copy/paste the complete error message, not just the tail.

Comment: I am seeing this: `libapache2-mod-php7.2` when your installing this: `php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-mcrypt'. Please check your php version with `php -version` and install the right version

Comment: i have changed to 7.2 and still getting:
Configurando libapache2-mod-php7.0 (7.0.29-1+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete libapache2-mod-php7.0 (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado el script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1
Configurando javascript-common (11) ...
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete javascript-common (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado el script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1

Answer (score 1):

I was able fix this by removing all php related and installed again by using:

```
sudo apt-get purge `dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "`
```